# how to toggle off an appended div

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a communication project where the user can use emojis. The way I've executed it so far is to create a partial HTML document and append that in when they click.

```
<script>
$('.chatbox-emoji-trigger').click(function() {
  $(this).append(("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/emoji_modal')) %>"));
});
</script>
```

now essentially what I'm trying to figure out is 2 things:

- how can I remove it (my guess is to change click to a toggle. The issue is that I append the HTML
- How can I make it so that when you click on anything but the div, it goes away

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following :

***1. how can I remove it (my guess is to change click to a toggle. The issue is that I append the HTML:***

You can assign the server side generated html to a js variable and use a specific selector ( could be any attribute that makes it unique ) and use it for adding/removing the element.

```
var dynamicHTML = "<span class='hello'>Hello</span>"; 

$('.chatbox-emoji-trigger').on("click",function() {
  if($(this).find('.hello').length === 0) // checks if the element exists
    $(this).append(dynamicHTML);  // if it doesn't , append it.
  else
     $(this).find('.hello').remove(); // else remove it 
});
```

***2. How can I make it so that when you click on anything but the div, it goes away***

For this, you can delegate a click handler to the document and use the event property to determine if it was triggered from a specific element or not.

```
$(document).on("click",function(e) {
     if(e.target.id != "div1") // checks if the click was triggered outside the div
       $(this).find('.hello').hide(); // if so, hide it.
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/8hvynxjx/1/